# Aggregating dataframe by occurrences of 3 columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Here is my data frame:

```
       Col1      Col2          Col3       Day       
 1       12         2  14031100000417017  70
 2       10         3  14031100000537996   6
 3        7         4  14031100000636479  11
 4       12         2  14031100001124050  70
 5       12         2  14031100001712518  70
 6       10         3  14031100001920801   6
```

How can I create a new data frame that shows me how many times `Col1`, `Col2` and `Day` occur with the same values? So in this example I would get:

```
       Col1      Col2          Col3       Day   Count    
 1      12         2   14031100000417017  70      3
 2      10         3   14031100000537996   6      2
 3       7         4   14031100000537996  11      1
```

Comment: I imagine you probably don't really want `Col3` in your final output since it varies across the n records. Also, the `Col3` you have in the third row of your example output doesn't appear alongside those values of `Col1` and `Col2` in your example data.

Comment: Yeah don't mind column 3...it's simply a transaction record for when the event took place.  The main idea is that Col1 and Col2 uniquely identify the entity but that entity can have multiple events (col3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good case for using the `dplyr` package, described in detail [here](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

```
library(dplyr)
my.dataframe %.% group_by(Col1, Col2, Day) %.% summarise(Count=n())
```

This can also be written as

```
summarise(group_by(my.dataframe, Col1, Col2, Day), Count=n())
```

Comment: Excellent thank you...worked great. And thank you everyone else for your answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can just use `ave` to create a "count" column. You don't really specify how you want to deal with "Col3", so I've left that out:

```
mydf$count <- ave(rep(1, nrow(mydf)), 
                  mydf[c("Col1", "Col2", "Day")], 
                  FUN = length)

mydf
#   Col1 Col2        Col3 Day count
# 1   12    2 1.40311e+16  70     3
# 2   10    3 1.40311e+16   6     2
# 3    7    4 1.40311e+16  11     1
# 4   12    2 1.40311e+16  70     3
# 5   12    2 1.40311e+16  70     3
# 6   10    3 1.40311e+16   6     2

unique(mydf[c("Col1", "Col2", "Day", "count")])
#   Col1 Col2 Day count
# 1   12    2  70     3
# 2   10    3   6     2
# 3    7    4  11     1
```

Answer (score 0):

And to round it off, here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(mydf)
mydt[, length(Col3), list(Col1, Col2, Day)]

#    Col1 Col2 Day V1
# 1:   12    2  70  3
# 2:   10    3   6  2
# 3:    7    4  11  1
```

The third argument is a list of grouping factors, while the second arg is the function that you'd like to apply to each group.

Answer (score 0):

Or using plyr:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Col1, Col2, Day), summarize, cnt = length(Col1))
```

or `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Col3 ~ Col1 + Col2 + Day, df, length)

  Col1 Col2 Day Col3

1   10    3   6    2
2    7    4  11    1
3   12    2  70    3
```